# SnapsToDevicePixels issue

Tags: wpf

In my WPF app, I have created few Line elements and added inside a StackPanel. The thickness for all lines is set to 0.5. But when I render it, sometimes few lines are appearing blur. I tried setting SnapsToDevicePixels in the StackPanel but this makes the lines completely invisible. Now if I increase the line thickness to 1 or greater than 1 then SnapsToDevicePixels is working properly.

I am creating Line as shown below:

```
private void CreateLine(Double y1, Double y2, Double x1, Double x2, Double width, Double height)
{
    Line line = new Line() { Y1 = y1, Y2 = y2, X1 = x1, X2 = x2, Width = width, Height = height };
}
```

Here, if LineThickness is set to 0.5, x1 and x2 values will be 0.25 (LineThickenss / 2) and width is 0.5 (LineThickness).

Is there any minimum pixel value required to be set in order to make the SnapsToDevicePixels work in WPF?

Comment: How did you determine that x1/x2 will be equal to 0.25?  According to your code it can be anything.

Comment: For a vertical line, I am just setting the value for x1 and x2 as LineThickness / 2. So if LineThickness is 0.5, x1 and x2 will be 0.25. Also, line width is set to the LineThickness value. Is there anything wrong am I doing? I want to create a vertical line with some defined LineThickness.

Comment: For starters I would avoid setting 'width' and 'height'  The other wrong thing you are doing is not presenting complete code in your question.

Answer (score 4):

I solved many of my `SnapToDevicePixels` issues by using `UseLayoutRounding` instead:

In your case:

```
<StackPanel UseLayoutRounding="True">
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

I don't know if this will solve your issue, but from my experience, it's worth a try!

Comment: UseLayoutRounding is not present in .Net 3.5. I have a custom control which is targeting to .Net 3.5 and 4.0 both. So I have to use SnapsToDevicePixels. Can you please tell me why SnapsToDevicePixels is not working properly with line thickness (pixel value) less than 1?

Comment: Perhaps it's rounding down to zero? Try using 0.51 (Is there a reason why you don't just use 1.0?)

Comment: Nothing changed. SnapsToDevicePixels is working only when the pixel value is greater or equal to 1.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a minimum per se.  The blurriness you are experiencing is due to how WPf handles drawing in general.  According to my experience you can't really do anything about it.  [Snapping to device pixels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.snapstodevicepixels.aspx) may give some reprieve, but can still be unpredictable.

Also there is a difference between a pixel and a WPF unit that makes things more complicated, though many techniques exist to translate between them.

A common approach to translating the pixel to WPF unit is:

```
Matrix m = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this).CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;
double dpiFactor = 1/m.M11;
double lineThickness = dpiFactor * 1;   // Repace '1' with desired pixel size.
```

Here is a useful article on the topic:
http://www.wpftutorial.net/DrawOnPhysicalDevicePixels.html

Comment: I tried doing the above calculation but still no change. Pixel value of 0.5 is not working properly with SnapsToDevicePixels. Sometimes lines are disappearing.

Comment: I have edited my question and provided the code for creating the line.

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to set fractional positions.

What means the half of WPF point?
WPF will interpret 1 point as 1/96 inch. It differs in pixels for distinct monitors (96 DPI, 300 DPI).

WPF considers 1 point as 1 pixel in the usual monitors with 96 DPI. And
[UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.snapstodevicepixels.aspx) works great. It tries to snap 0.5 pixel to the monitor grid. There are two results: enlarged version two one pixel or shortened version to 0 pixel (disappears).

If for some reason there is a need for exact 1 pixel (not 1 point) positioning then use [GuidelineSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

With .NET 4  or higher it is better to use [Layout Rounding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2009/08/27/layout-rounding.aspx). It calculates pixel offsets at the UI position measuring level. While `SnapsToDevicePixels` works at the render level. The minus for `Layout Rounding` is that it is bad for dynamic moving.